# Linked List - EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I believe the error is because I incorrectly deleted a node but I would appreciate any advice

Tags: c++, list, exc-bad-access

```
void LinkedList::insertBack(int stationID, int year, int month, double temp) {
Node* newNode = new Node(stationID, year, month, temp);
if (tail != nullptr)
    tail->next = newNode; //ERROR - EXC_BAD_ACCESS code = 2
tail = newNode;
if (head == nullptr) { 
    head = newNode; 
}
}
```

Here is a part of my code from a project that takes in data and puts them into linked list. I wrote in the error and on what line it appears. I don't believe the actual problem is in this function but I would appreciate any help at all. Thank you! I have attached the rest of my .cpp file for this underneath. I have attached my main.cpp also.

```
LinkedList::LinkedList(string name) :
head(nullptr), tail(nullptr), name(name) {}

// Destructor
LinkedList::~LinkedList() {
clear();
cout << "LinkedList destructor called" << endl;
}

//Default constructor
LinkedList::LinkedList(){
    cout << "LinkedList constructor called." << endl;
    dataObj = new int;
    *dataObj = 0;
    return;
}

//Copy Constructor
LinkedList::LinkedList(const LinkedList& origClass) {
     cout << "Copy Constructor called." << endl;
    dataObj = new int;
    *dataObj = *(origClass.dataObj);
    return;
}

 //Copy Assignment Operator
LinkedList& LinkedList::operator=(const LinkedList& objToCopy){
     cout << "Assignment op called." << endl;

    if (this != &objToCopy) {
        delete dataObj;
        dataObj = new int;
        *dataObj = *(objToCopy.dataObj);
    }
     return *this;
 }

void LinkedList::empty() {
    if (head)
        delete head;
}

void LinkedList::setName(string name) {
this->name = name;
}

string LinkedList::getName() const{
    return name;
}

void LinkedList::insertFront(int stationID, int year, int month, double temp) {
    Node* newNode = new Node(stationID, year, month, temp);
    newNode->next = head; // attach to list
    head = newNode;
    if (tail == nullptr) { // empty list
    tail = newNode; // only node is both head and tail
}
 }

void LinkedList::insertBack(int stationID, int year, int month, double temp) {
    Node* newNode = new Node(stationID, year, month, temp);
    if (tail != nullptr)
        tail->next = newNode; // attach to list
    tail = newNode;
    if (head == nullptr) { // empty list
        head = newNode; // only node is both head and tail
    }
}


void LinkedList::insertBack(int stationID, string command, int firstYear, int      lastYear) {

    Node* newNode = new Node(stationID, command, firstYear, lastYear);
    if (tail != nullptr)
        tail->next = newNode; // attach to list
    tail = newNode;
    if (head == nullptr) { // empty list
    head = newNode; // only node is both head and tail
    }
}



void LinkedList::clear() {
    Node* del = head;
    while (del != NULL) {
        head = head->next;
        delete del;
        del = head;
     }
     head = tail = NULL;
 }

int LinkedList::size()
{
    int cnt = 0;
     Node* node = head;
    while (node != NULL) {
        cnt++;
        node = node->next;
    }
    return cnt;
}

void LinkedList::print() const {
    print(cout);
}

void LinkedList::print(ostream& os) const {
    os << this;
}

//Temp List
double LinkedList::getStationID(int index) const {
     Node* current= head;
    double count = 0.0;
     double ID = 0.0;
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (count == index) {
            ID = current->stationID;
        }
        count++;
        current = current->next;
    }
    return ID;
}

double LinkedList::getYear(int index) const {
    Node* current= head;
    double count = 0.0;
    double year = 0.0;
     while (current != NULL) {
        if (count == index) {
             year = current->year;
        }
        count++;
        current = current->next;
    }
    return year;
}
double LinkedList::getMonth(int index) const {
    Node* current= head;
    double count = 0.0;
    double month = 0.0;
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (count == index) {
            month = current->month;
        }
        count++;
        current = current->next;
      }
    return month;
 }
double LinkedList::getTemp(int index) const {
    Node* current= head;
    double count = 0.0;
    double temp = 0.0;
     while (current != NULL) {
        if (count == index) {
            temp = current->temperature;
        }
        count++;
        current = current->next;
    }
    return temp;
 }

 //Query List
 string LinkedList::getCommand(int index) {
    Node* current= head;
    double count = 0.0;
    string phrase = "";
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (count == index) {
            phrase = current->command;
        }
        count++;
        current = current->next;
    }
    return phrase;
}
double LinkedList::getFirstYear(int index) const {
    Node* current= head;
    double count = 0.0;
    double first = 0.0;
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (count == index) {
            first = current->firstYear;
        }
         count++;
         current = current->next;
     }
     return first;
}
double LinkedList::getSecondYear(int index) const {
    Node* current= head;
    double count = 0.0;
    double last = 0.0;
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (count == index) {
            last = current->lastYear;
        }
        count++;
        current = current->next;
    }
    return last;
}


Node* LinkedList::search(double val)
{
    Node* node = head;

    /* traverse the list */
    while (node != NULL) {
        /* Target! */
        if(node->value == val)
        {
            return node;
        }
        /* move to the next one */
        node = node->next;
    }
    return NULL;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const LinkedList& ll) {
    os << ll.getName() << " {";
    Node* current = ll.head;
    if (current == nullptr) {
        os << " <Empty List>";
    }
    while (current != nullptr) {
        if (current != ll.head)
            cout << ",";
        cout << " " << current->stationID << ",";
        cout << " " << current->year << ",";
        cout << " " << current->month << ",";
        cout << " " << current->temperature;
        cout << " " << current->command;
        cout << " " << current->firstYear;
        cout << " " << current->lastYear;
        current = current->next;
     }
    cout << " }";
    return os;
}
```

MAIN.CPP

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <ios>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "LinkedList.hpp"
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include "Node.h"
int roundNum (float a) {
    return floor(a + 0.5);
}

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {


    //What I need
    int stationID = 0, year = 0, month = 0, firstYear = 0, lastYear = 0;
    int maxCount = 0;
    int maxNumber = 0;
    int myCount = 0;


bool foundStation = false;
bool foundFirst = false;
bool foundLast = false;
string unknown = "unknown";
double temp = 0.0;
double total = 0.0;
double average = 0.0;
double count = 0.0;
int const CURRENT_YEAR = 2016;
string command = "";
vector<double>avg;
vector<double>mode;
vector<string>final;



LinkedList tempList;
LinkedList queryList;
//Read this file
ifstream tempFile = ifstream("3linetemp.dat");
ifstream queryFile = ifstream("queries.dat");

ofstream outputFile = ofstream("results.dat");

//Linked List for Temperature Data

while (tempFile >> stationID >> year >> month >> temp) {
    try {
    if (year < 1800 || year > CURRENT_YEAR) {throw runtime_error("Error.");}
    if (month < 0 || month > 12) {throw runtime_error("Error.");}
    if (temp == -99.99) {throw runtime_error("Error.");}


    tempList.insertBack(stationID, year, month, temp);
    }
   catch(runtime_error& excpt) {cout << excpt.what() << endl;}
}

//Query Data
while (queryFile >> stationID >> command >> firstYear >> lastYear) {
    queryList.insertBack(stationID, command, firstYear, lastYear);
}

//Get Average and Mode
for (int i = 0; i < queryList.size(); i++) {

   //AVERAGE
    if (queryList.getCommand(i) == "AVG") {
        for (int j = 0; j < tempList.size(); j++) {
            if (queryList.getStationID(i) == tempList.getStationID(j)) { foundStation = true;
                if (tempList.getYear(j) >= queryList.getFirstYear(i)) { foundFirst = true;
                    if (tempList.getYear(j) <= queryList.getSecondYear(i)) { foundLast = true;
                        total += tempList.getTemp(j);
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (foundStation == false ||foundFirst == false || foundLast == false) /*Indicates no matching stationID*/ {final.push_back(unknown);}
        else {
            foundStation = false;
            foundFirst = false;
            foundLast = false;
            average = total/count;
            final.push_back(to_string(average));
            average = 0.0;
            total = 0.0;
            count = 0.0;
        }
    }
    //MODE
    //Get possible modes
    if (queryList.getCommand(i) == "MODE") {
        for (int j = 0; j < tempList.size(); j++) {
            if (queryList.getStationID(i) == tempList.getStationID(j)) { foundStation = true;
                if (tempList.getYear(j) >= queryList.getFirstYear(i)) { foundFirst = true;
                    if (tempList.getYear(j) <= queryList.getSecondYear(i)) { foundLast = true;

                        int a = roundNum(tempList.getTemp(j));
                        mode.push_back(a);
                }
            }
        }
    }      //If you can't find station ID
        if (foundStation == false || foundFirst == false || foundLast == false) {final.push_back(unknown);}
        //Find Mode
        else {
            foundStation = false;
            foundFirst = false;
            foundLast = false;
            auto minmax = std::minmax_element(std::begin(mode), std::end(mode));
            int max = *(minmax.second);
            for (int i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
                myCount = ::count(mode.begin(), mode.end(), i);
            if (maxCount < myCount) {
                maxCount = myCount;
                maxNumber = i;
            }
        }
        final.push_back(to_string(maxNumber));
        }
    }
}

cout << "File created." << endl;

  //Make Results File
    for (int i = 0; i < queryList.size(); i++) {
         outputFile << queryList.getStationID(i) << " " <<    queryList.getFirstYear(i) << " " << queryList.getSecondYear(i)  << " " << queryList.getCommand(i) << " " << final.at(i) << endl;
}

for (int i = 0; i < final.size(); i++) {
    cout << final.at(i) << endl;
}
}
```

NODE.H

```
#include "LinkedList.hpp"
#include "Temperature.hpp"
#include "Query.hpp"
#include "Node.h"
struct Node {
    int stationID, year, month, firstYear, lastYear;
    std::string command;

    double temperature;
    double value = 0;;
    Node* next = nullptr;

     //Temp Node
    Node(int stationID, int year, int month, double temperature) :  stationID(stationID), year(year), month(month), temperature(temperature) {}
    //Query Node
    Node (int stationID, std::string command, int firstYear, int lastYear) : stationID(stationID), command(command), firstYear(firstYear), lastYear(lastYear) {}

    Node() : stationID(0), year(0), month(0), temperature(0), next(nullptr) {}

};

 #endif /* Node_h */
```

Comment: 1) Where is the `main` program to see how you're using the linked list?  2)  Are you using the debugger to debug your program?  3) You should have unit-tested your linked list basic functionality, such as element insertion **before** proceeding to write this entire class.  At the stage of where your code is now, insertion into the list should not have been a problem *if the class was unit-tested*.

Comment: Your copy constructor and assignment operator are completely wrong.  The copy constructor does not initialize all the pointer members, and I see no actual copying of the passed-in linked list to `this`.  The same with the assignment operator -- there is no real copying going on, but some minimal "here I got called" code.

Answer (score 0):

I see multiple problems with the shown code. However, since the shown code fails to meet the requirements of a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) there's a small possibility that the cause of the crash is something else. However, I think it's likely that one of the following bugs is responsible for the undefined behavior that leads to a crash, and since you "appreciate any advice", this would qualify as a valid answer:

1. `insertBack()` fails to initialize `newNode->next` to `nullptr`. If `Node`'s constructor does not initialize it by default, this will result in an uninitialized `next` pointer on the `tail` node. EDIT: you posted additional code that shows that `next` is default-initialized.
2. The copy constructor fails to initialize `head` and `tail` to `nullptr`. The default constructor also fails to do that, as well.

I suspect that you are seeing a crash as a result of calling `insertBack()` on a copy-constructed or a default-constructed list, whose `tail` pointer was not initialized, as explained above. If so, this will be a textbook example of why when a C++ program crashes at a particular line, it doesn't necessarily mean that this is where the bug is.

But, still, in order to confirm the reason for the observed undefined behavior, it will be necessary to see a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

P.S. It is also unclear whether the copy-constructor, and the assignment operator, should be making a copy of the actual list. If so, then the failure to do so would be another bug.

Comment: Thank you. I have attached my main.cpp and my node.h file. I believe this will meet the requirements. I initialized my Node* next to nullptr in my header file. Do I need to do this in my insertBack() function as well?

Comment: No, the default initialization will be sufficient. However your example fails at least the "minimal" and "complete" part. A large part of the posted code is obviously completely irrelevant to the bug, so this does not meet the "minimal" part. The "complete" requirement means that anyone can compile and execute the posted code to reproduce the issue. The shown code still fails, in several ways, to meet the "complete" requirement. The shown example is not **complete** unless it contains everything that anyone needs to be able to **verify** and reproduce the question asked.